# Update Page without timeinterval() method with JQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a webpage, where you can comment on.
What I want is whenever somebody enters a comment, this comment should be appear in all users window.

There is a Jquery code that handle inserting comment to database without refreshing it. However for new comments, I am calling a php file with ajax to control whether there is a new comment or not. I need to control this php file "continuous time" however, all I can do is refreshing it with timeinterval() method.

Is there any way to invoke javascript through input of another user?

Sorry for my English..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is server push. You should have a look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [comet](http://cometd.org/) if you want server push on your system.

Comment: It's just a suggestion on possible alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, does loadin php page with ajax in every two seconds (as you refer pulling information) create heavy workload on server?

Comment: It depends. If everytime you ping your server, there is no update then it's a wasted request. Think if 500 people have your site open that will create 500 requests every few seconds that might return empty data. On the other hand, if you use a server push, this won't be the case

Comment: @Tim yup, that's true. As opposed to opening and closing 500 connections every 2 seconds this sounds better

Answer (score 0):

Nope there is not. You can only pull data from a server, no push possible.
There are workarounds possible where a JS connection to the server is just kept open thus making it possible to send and receive data without a new request (I think Google Wave used it). But those workarounds probably need changes on the server side.
Whats wrong with a timer?

Answer (score 0):

As JohnP and Thorben said: It is possible to use a long lasting request. This technique is called comet and you can read the basics here: [comet programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). If you want example, search for [Ajax chat](http://www.google.com/q=ajax+chat), good luck.